# How to multithread post request in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm trying to multithread post requests using python to send hashes to malwarebazaar.
1st I'm reading hashes from file, then I'm trying to multithread it, but I'm get stucked
My code don't use all hashes, where it is going wrong?

```
import re
import json
import sys
import requests
from time import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
f=open('hashes.txt')
lines= f.readlines()
url='https://mb-api.abuse.ch/api/v1'
array=[]
for line in lines:
    line=line.replace('\n','')
    data={'query':'get_info','hash':line}
    array.append(data)
#print(array)

#start=time()
print(url)
def function(url):
        html = requests.post(url, data=array,stream=True)
        print(html.json())
        return html

start = time()

processes = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    for url in url:
     processes.append(executor.submit(function, url))

#for task in as_completed(processes):
#   print(task.result())

print(f'Time taken: {time() - start}')
#c = Counter(array)
#print(c)
```

Comment: You haven't given any explanation on what's going wrong

Comment: Exceptions in `function` are not handled in this code, because the resulting futures are never polled. Uncomment the loop containing `task.result()` to see what goes wrong.

Comment: How come you are using `stream=True`? If you set stream to True when making a request, Requests cannot release the connection back to the pool unless you consume all the data or call Response.close. This can lead to inefficiency with connections. If you find yourself partially reading request bodies (or not reading them at all) while using stream=True, you should make the request within a with statement to ensure it’s always closed. Example: `with requests.get(url, data=array, stream=True) as r:`

Comment: @roganjosh
It takes random hashes from file 
`print(url)
def function(url):
        html = requests.post(url, data=x,stream=True)
        print(html.json())
        return html`

Comment: @user56700
I got answers from my requests, but it takes random hashes 
`print(url)
def function(url):
        html = requests.post(url, data=x,stream=True)
        print(html.json())
        return html` and `processes = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    for x in array:
     processes.append(executor.submit(function, url))`

Comment: Please provide some test data from your `hashes.txt`

Comment: `bd4db5d00ba4633516169666635be7dee18a1916585a32def38498c0062b48a7` 
`92b2ba8088561d9b67f64ee433b0f9a82599ad194672ab15f689ded2ed4d3c51`80a606be75ab17bfd2096e6f1efbb0df1968e72b4337cff0a0fc3016b088e794`
`b164e9f4c24d002fe0d8975972e569b3873d0d8ae3e6075f548498e261874b42`
`123`
`f676742212a35929267bfd3750a0bbd5609de0cc2ad43955331d2b3f27af6e8f`
The last two hashes should returns json response 'illegal hash' and the last one should return info from malwarebazaar

Comment: @Dalador I added an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i got it working:

Test data (hashes.txt)

```
bd4db5d00ba4633516169666635be7dee18a1916585a32def38498c0062b48a7
92b2ba8088561d9b67f64ee433b0f9a82599ad194672ab15f689ded2ed4d3c51
80a606be75ab17bfd2096e6f1efbb0df1968e72b4337cff0a0fc3016b088e794
b164e9f4c24d002fe0d8975972e569b3873d0d8ae3e6075f548498e261874b42
f676742212a35929267bfd3750a0bbd5609de0cc2ad43955331d2b3f27af6e8f
```

The code:

```
import re, sys, requests, time, concurrent.futures
url='https://mb-api.abuse.ch/api/v1'
array=[]
with open("hashes.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        array.append({'query':'get_info','hash':line.rstrip("\n")})

def function(payload):
    with requests.post(url, data=payload,stream=True) as response:
        html = response.json()
        return(html)

start = time.time()

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    processes = {executor.submit(function, query) for query in array}
    for result in concurrent.futures.as_completed(processes):
        print(result.result()['query_status'])

print(f'Time taken: {time.time() - start}')
```

Results:

```
hash_not_found
hash_not_found
hash_not_found
hash_not_found
ok
Time taken: 1.113807201385498
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
Now I understand my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can use greenlets to make parallel requests.

```
from gevent.pool import Group

print (starttime)
group = Group() #start parallel fn calls
group.spawn(DoRequest,param1,param2)
group.spawn(DoRequest,param1,param2)
group.spawn(DoRequest,param1,param2)
group.join() #wait for all to finish
print (endtime)

def DoRequest(param1,param2):
    #make request and get response
```